# Write x in terms of y for $x^x$ = y

Tags: logarithms, exponential-function

Is there a closed form for $x^x = y$ (for positive real numbers)?

I'm not sure if this has been answered already; google search doesn't do well with symbols so its hard for me to search this up.

Comment: Hint : Use Lambert W.

Comment: duplicate: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2968487/inverse-of-xx-using-lambert-w-function

Comment: yep the duplicate is what I was looking for

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1035539/can-xxx-k-be-solved-using-the-w-function (this is about power tower of x)